# Homework assignment to fill mock array with random values

Tags: java, matrix

How can I create x*y matrix (where x <= y) with random integers (from 0 to 9) which has at least x zeros and max (x*y)/2 in java?

Size of matrix (x,y) is given. Also I would like to know how to use this matrix with same integers with same index in other class (for example 'public class Game{...}'). I'm a beginner so please make it easy for me :)

**My code so far:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Solution {

    int a[][];

    public void P(int x, int y){
        Random r = new Random();
        a = new int[x][y];

        for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
                a[i][j] = r.nextInt(10);
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();

        int zeros = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
                if(a[i][j]==0){
                    zeros ++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(zeros);
    }   

    public int[][] getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: SE is not for homework questions. Instead, state your exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
    a = new int[x][y];

    int noZeros = r.nextInt((y*x)/2-x) + x;

    boolean z[][] = new boolean[x][y];


    for (int i = 0; i < noZeros; i++) {
        z[r.nextInt(x)][r.nextInt(y)] = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            if (!z[i][j]) {
                a[i][j] = r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            }
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }



    System.out.println();

    int zeros = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] == 0) {
                zeros++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(zeros);
```

In my solution I create first boolean matrix, which represents zeros, then I chose random number, but from 1 to 9.

Comment: Thank you! :D can you also help me with my other question?
how to use this matrix with same integers with same index in other class (for example 'public class Game{...}')

Comment: I don't know if I understand, but if you want to use array a in class Game, class Game has to extends class Solution or you have to create an new object class Solution in class Game and call the method getA().

Answer (score 1):

I would first determine how many 0s you will have in the matrix, getting a random `int` from within your min/max bound. Then I would calculate the other `xy - numZeros` random integers. Finally, for each cell in the matrix, I would pick a random element from a combined list (your 0s + other random integers, removing the element when it is picked).